# How to use CFileDialog correctly

Tags: c++, com, visual-studio-2012, sdl

I am working on a SDL application, using VS2012, targeting windows.

I want to do the following:

- Have a file-open dialog
- Have a file-save as dialog

To do this, I implemented some functions like this:

```
#include <afxdlgs.h>
/// This function gets a path to save a file to from the user
/// \return             true if function succeeds, false otherwise
/// \param  pPath       String to save path in
/// \param  name        default file name
/// \param  extensions  default file extensions separated by |
///                     "Text File (*.txt)|*.txt|Document File (*.doc)|*.doc|All Files(*.*)|*.*||"
bool Prompt::fileOpen( std::string * pPath, const std::string & defaultName, const std::string & defaultExtension, const std::string & extensions )
{
    //return false;

    CFileDialog dlg(
        true,                                   // true for File Open dialog box
        defaultExtension.c_str(),               // The default file name extension
        defaultName.c_str(),                    // The default file name
        OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_NOCHANGEDIR,    // bunch of flags http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh5hz49d.aspx
        extensions.c_str()
        );

    auto result = dlg.DoModal();
    if(result != IDOK) return false; // failed
    pPath->assign(dlg.GetPathName());
    return true;
}
```

Now unfortunately, this causes a compile issue on debug:
Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version.
Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]

So under Configuration > General > Use of MFC
I set it to "Use MFC in a Shared DLL"

Now it compiles, but does not work as expected.

I get a run-time exception:

Unhandled exception at 0x51A9A072 (mfc110d.dll) in App.exe:
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

winmain.cpp line 28

```
if (!pThread->InitInstance())
```

basically pThread is a nullptr

Note that if I remove the include of

```
#include <afxdlgs.h>
```

and the fileOpen function my app works as expected.

I am not sure how to fix this issue, any help will be nice.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're not using MFC for the rest of the program so why start here?
You should probably use [`GetOpenFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: I managed to solve my issue by using this the "common file dialog" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @aCuria can you share your piece of code?

Comment: Hi Hassan, I never did get CFileDialog to work. You should try using microsoft's newere api's

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that your winmain-initialisation did not run, because stl has its own main-function. You can either call winmain at an apropriate place to setup event-loop and all the other things, or have your own winmain, like described there: http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=1513&sid=be1738a196fe7ca5d72ea7a894ddc5b7

Comment: Well, this might not be the whole story. As in written in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w04bs753(v=vs.80).aspx, applications without winmain: "For a console application, which does not use the MFC-supplied WinMain function, you must call AfxWinInit directly to initialize MFC. "

Comment: Simply calling AfxWinInit does not do anything.