# How to add FileDialog to Windows MFC Dialog Application in VS2022

Tags: c++, mfc, filedialog

I have created an Windows MFC Dialog C++ application with VS2022 it builds and loads as expected.
What I am trying to figure out is how to add the FileDialog class/function etc to open a file's.
I know about using main dialog controls to add a button and launch function from a button press etc.

But how to add the FileDialog class to the project I am struggling to figure out, what are the steps please?

Many thanks in advance IMK
PS I last did this in 2004 with very old version of VS, but how to do it in VS2022 has me stuck, sorry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use CFileDialog correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322466/how-to-use-cfiledialog-correctly)

Comment: to be honest MFC is somewhat legacy at this point, it was popular 20 years ago, now it is only portable because wine was able to run it, however its coding style is not modern, you should instead use something like QT or wxWidgets or even FLTK

Comment: You don't get the Doc/View infrastructure for a dialog-based MFC application. You'll have to add "file open" support manually. Not exactly hard, though I don't know how to convince `CFileDialog` to use the `IFileDialog` implementation. You cannot click through the IDE to get this added. Occasionally, a developer's job is to actually write code.

Comment: Many thanks to all for the most constructive comments, figure it out easy.
You know sometimes you just too focused and can't see the wood for the trees.
Brgds IMK